# Can't I move element by using "element.style.top = window.scrollY"?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make some kind of floating input element, making it follows the scroll.
finally I made it and there is code below.

What I am wondering about is if i change "setText(window.scrollY)" to "document.querySelector(".code).style.top = window.scrollY" it doesn't give me the same result.
I think it is same code but later code doesn't work.
Can anybody tell me why?
thank you

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Input() {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
  
  window.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    function () {
      if (typeof document.querySelector(".code") === "undefined") {
        alert("TT");
      } else {
        setScroll(window.scrollY);              // *this part
      }
    },
    { passive: true }
  );

  return (
    <input
      style={{
        top: text
      }}
      className="code"
      autoComplete="on"
      placeholder="Write code please"
    />
  );
}

export default Input;
```

Comment: Have you checked what is set to in your browser dev tools inspect facility. scrollY gives a number, you need to add the px string to make it a valid value for top.

Comment: thank you Haworth! you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 setScroll(window.scrollY+"px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `useRef()` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of `document.querySelector(".code")`. React works with [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html), so when `document.querySelector(".code")` runs, the rea DOM would not be available yet. But you can use `useRef` to grab the virtual DOM and perform your manipulations on it. You can access the element with the ref's `.current` property.

Secondly, the scroll event handler would need to be wrapped in React's `useEffect` hook, to ensure it is added when the component mounts.

Comment: thank you. I'm actually new at react so I didn't know well about that part. I'll search and learn more about hooks and apply it